# Cannot open gedit using sudo in Ubuntu 16

Tags: gedit

Command used:

```
sudo gedit /var/www/html/testphp.php
Failed to register: Timeout was reached
```

Comment: I had the same problem. The command "killall gedit" fixed it!

Comment: **NOT A DUPLICATE**: The indicated duplicate does not report the same error.  Nor does it have the same solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [know and confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1625819).  Gedit is stuck in an unterminated state.  Rebooting your computer will remove the terminated state and it should work again.

To avoid having to reboot you can run a standalone instance with the `-s` argument:

```
 $ sudo gedit -s /var/www/html/testphp.php
```

To avoid rebooting and continue working in your current session you can install and alternate text editor such as **kate** or **geany**.

```
$ sudo apt install [kate or geany]
```

Replace the bracket entry with one of the alternate editors.  Then run the editor from the Ubuntu Dash Search.