Getting GTK error while closing gedit opened from Terminal
I recently dual booted my Lenovo e15 gen 2 laptop. I am using ubuntu 24.04 lts version.
First I tried gedit command ie
gedit test.text
Unknown command gedit so I tried sudo apt install gedit
While running that command i got something like this.refer image for the error i got
It worked then I tried gedit test.text again it worked but when I closed the window I am getting
Please refer the picture for the error i am encountering

see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/883202/1698042
